# How do I correct the "Command output already redirected" error

Tags: powershell, parsing, error-handling

Sorry if this is a newbie question. But I have been experimenting with gcloud Text to Speech API and tring to get the output saved as a text file.

I did that by adding | out-file result.txt to the final line of instructions below.It worked once but since that it just returns an error that output is already redirected.

Any ideas as how to solve this?

---

```
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
>> $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }
>>
>> Invoke-WebRequest `
>>   -Method POST `
>>   -Headers $headers `
>>   -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
>>   -InFile f:\request.json `
>>   -Uri "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" | Select-Object -Expand Content

//**Errors:**
At line:6 char:1
+ >>   -Headers $headers `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The output stream for this command is already redirected.
At line:7 char:1
+ >>   -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The output stream for this command is already redirected.
At line:8 char:1
+ >>   -InFile f:\request.json `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
The output stream for this command is already redirected.
At line:9 char:1
+ >>   -Uri "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" |  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
The output stream for this command is already redirected.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StreamAlreadyRedirected
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `-ContentType` parameter? (you can manually add a `Content-Type = "application/json; charset=utf-8"` header to the `$headers` dict instead)

Comment: No, unfortunately it gives the same result (with or without adding to the $header)

Comment: Why do you keep continuing the same command over 6 lines? Try doing the command without the plethora of backticks.

Comment: Remove `>>` in the beginning of each line.
It seems you have copied the command from the console window including [Continuation Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_line_editing#add-a-line).

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was something staring me in the face - but removing the Continuation Prompts worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks 7cc - this was the answer:
Remove >> in the beginning of each line. It seems you have copied the command from the console window including Continuation Prompts. And they were interpreted as redirect commands.